# Looping through tagged resources in AWS RDS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-rds

Basically, I'm trying to target clusters based on their tag. In the code below I can target the cluster with the tag `AutoOn` and `true`
However, if I have one other cluster with tags how can I also include that in my script so I can also start it up? Is it another if statement?

I'm a noob to Python but have created this script that successfully targets the first cluster and powers it on.

```py
def handler(event, context):
# Step one: get all DB clusters.
    response = rds_client.describe_db_clusters(
        MaxRecords=100
    )

    # Make an empty list for cluster info storage.
    clusters = [] # empty list of no items.

    # Get the initial results.
    clusters.append(response['DBClusters'])

    # If 'Marker' is present in the response, we have more to get.
    while 'Marker' in response:
        old_marker = response['Marker']
        response = rds_client.describe_db_clusters(
            MaxRecords=100,
            Marker = old_marker
        )
        clusters.append(response['DBClusters'])
        # Cycles back up to repeat the pagination.

    for cluster in clusters:
        for test in cluster:
            for tag in test['TagList']:
                if tag['Key'] == "AutoOn":
                    if tag['Value'] == "true":
                        continue  # move to the next record.

        # Stop the instance.
        rds_client.start_db_cluster(
            DBClusterIdentifier=test['DBClusterIdentifier']
        )
```

I tried this as a way to target cluster 1 AND cluster 2. The code runs fine in a Lambda function and doesn't produce any errors but it doesn't start the RDS clusters

```py
for tag in test['TagList']:
    if ('Key' == 'AutoOn'
          and 'Value' == 'true'
            ): 
             
    if ('Key' == 'AutoOn2'
          and 'Value' == 'true'):
             rds_client.start_db_cluster(
        DBClusterIdentifier=test['DBClusterIdentifier']
```

Comment: Could you add the content of the response? Without it it's really hard to help. Could you also explain what you want to do with other tag?

Comment: Please print the response of rds_client.start_db_cluster

Answer (score 0):

This code works and checks the first if statement for the tags and powers on before successfully moving to the second if statement and checking for the relevant tags

```
for tag in test['TagList']:
    if tag['Key'] == 'TestRDS' and tag['Value'] == 'true':
        rds_client.stop_db_cluster(
            DBClusterIdentifier=test['DBClusterIdentifier'] 
        )  
    if tag['Key'] == 'QARDS' and tag['Value'] == 'true':
        rds_client.stop_db_cluster(
            DBClusterIdentifier=test['DBClusterIdentifier']
        )
```